# Trying to open folders ending with - in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to open png files with python. I just started but gets stuck when trying to access files in folders ending with - , the code works fine when I choose folders that don't end with - . 
My idea was that - might be a special sign in Python somehow but I could not find any documentation for that. I am a beginner at Python so the answer might be obvious, you can see my code below.

```
import glob
import os

foldername='M:\mystuff\foldername-'

for pngfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(foldername, '*.png')):
    print 'found'
```

Comment: Check and see if that foldername works if you put an escape character ahead of the dash. I can think of no reason why that should work, but then thats how half my code fixes are solved...

Comment: it is working actually - what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried change name on that actual folder and it still doesn't work, but if I copy the png to another folder and open that folder it works.

Comment: ok I've tried it in console so it worked the reason is described in gre_gor's answer

Comment: And all of the foldernames consists of 14 numbers followed by - , example: 20150414152425-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backshashes aren't escaped, so your `"\f"` gets converted into an `"\x0C"` character.

You should escape the string

```
'M:\\mystuff\\foldername-'
```

or use a raw string

```
r'M:\mystuff\foldername-'
```